# Заменить даты в dataframe на последовательную нумерацию с условием, что если дата меняется то идет следующая цифра нумерации

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
from ast import parse
import pandas 
import openpyxl
import numpy
x=[] 
data = pandas.read_csv('data.csv', sep = ';') 
data_result = pandas.pivot_table(data, index=['skv','date ', 'diaphragm'])
df = data_result.reset_index()
date = list(df['date '])
for i in range(len(df['date '])):
    df['date '] = df.groupby('date ')['date '].cumcount().add()      
print(df)
```

Всем привет!

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне дописать код так, чтобы столбец с датами пронумеровался, как на скриншоте?

[image: data]

Comment: Почитайте, почему не надо в вопросы выкладывать скриншоты. https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться группировкой:

```
df["date"] = df.groupby("date").ngroup()+1
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Для этих целей подойдет функция pandas.factorize[1](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html#pandas-factorize). Так как она нумерует уникальные значения с 0, то добавляем единицу и перезаписываем столбец.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep = ';')
codes, uniques = pd.factorize(df['date'])
df['date'] = codes + 1
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!